# How do I get the Robotiq force-torque sensor to work with ROS Kinetic?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Our lab is using Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04 and we can't connect to our FT300 sensor with ROS. Using just the instructions in the FT300 manual (under the Development Package section), I was able to get sensor readings to show up in the terminal, so I do at least know my computer can make the connection. But `rosrun robotiq_force_torque_sensor rq_sensor`, which should do the same thing, just gives me lines and lines of "Waiting for sensor connection..." indefinitely. I've tried the following in various combinations:

- Using both the jade-devel and kinetic-devel branches of the Robotiq repository
- Specifying the exact \dev\ttyUSB* device that the sensor shows up as
- Modifying my files using TheDash's pull request that allows FT300 support

Unfortunately I lack the technical knowledge to know what the source of this problem is. As far as I can tell, the only fix is to downgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 and Indigo, since another lab has been able to get their FT300 working that way. Has anyone else run into this problem and managed to solve it somehow? Otherwise, can anyone give me a rough idea of how much headway has been made towards making this possible?

Thanks for reading.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304267/how-do-i-get-the-robotiq-force-torque-sensor-to-work-with-ros-kinetic?/) by [mosslab](https://answers.ros.org/users/37736/mosslab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2018-09-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-26**:
If you're referring to [ros-industrial/robotiq](https://github.com/ros-industrial/robotiq), then I would suggest posting an issue on the tracker, as Kinetic is supposed to be supported with the latest PRs merged.

**Comment by [Meric](https://answers.ros.org/users/40534/meric/) on 2019-04-24**:
Does FT300 Sensor connected to your own PC or does it connected to a central pc, like UR5 Robot pcs?

**Comment by [geojenks](https://answers.ros.org/users/69397/geojenks/) on 2021-02-05**:
Hi, I'm having a similiar problem now. If I put this into the terminal I get:

> > > rosrun robotiq_ft_sensor rq_sensor
> > > [ INFO] [1612536217.472181179]: No device filename specified. Will attempt to discover Robotiq force torque sensor.
> > > [ INFO] [1612536218.010196358]: Waiting for sensor connection...
> > > [ INFO] [1612536219.548476111]: Waiting for sensor connection...

and so on. How were you managing to get readings to show up in the terminal? I have made sure that I have chown the relevant USB connection to my username. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This problem was solved here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/112568/how-do-i-allow-a-non-default-user-to-use-serial-device-ttyusb0

Unfortunately the chosen answer at that link is not what solved it--I already added myself to dialout, but running `sudo chown [me] /dev/ttyUSB1` allowed me to connect to the sensor. As it looks like I will have to run this every time I plug the sensor in, I'm going to look into some of the other answers in that thread.

---

Originally posted by [mosslab](https://answers.ros.org/users/37736/mosslab/) with karma: 28 on 2018-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [porkPy](https://answers.ros.org/users/38648/porkpy/) on 2018-12-19**:
@mosslab
I am having the very same issue. I have added myself to the dialout and created a udev rules file but nothing has changed.
Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Thanks,
Dom.

Edit: After a day of trying to work out why this was not working, I finally decided to simply turn off the Robotiq force/torque sensor and turn it back on again.
It is now communicating with ROS.

(it's always something stupid!)

**Comment by [Meric](https://answers.ros.org/users/40534/meric/) on 2019-04-24**:
Does FT300 Sensor connected to your own PC or does it connected to a central pc, like UR5 Robot pcs?